# Batik - how do I find the "fill" colour of a TextNode?

Tags: java, svg, batik

I am trying to use Batik to perform an SVG conversion and it is going alright except that I can't seem to find out where the value of the `fill` attribute for the original SVG document is stored on the Batik `TextNode` element. So in my SVG I have the following:

```
<text x="276.1875" y="120.390625" text-anchor="middle" font="10px &quot;Arial&quot;"
      stroke="none" fill="#ffffff" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-anchor: middle; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; font-stretch: normal; font-size: 10px; line-height: normal; font-family: Arial;"
      font-size="10px" font-family="Arial">
     <tspan dy="3.5" >Proportion </tspan>
</text>
```

This works fine, but when I am using my custom `TextPainter` ( through a generic Bridge ) to try and process the TextNode I find the following:

```
   public void paint(TextNode node, Graphics2D g2d )
   {
      AttributedCharacterIterator aci = node.getAttributedCharacterIterator();
      Paint colourInfo = (Paint)aci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.FOREGROUND); //null
      Paint bgInfo = (Paint)aci.getAttribute(TextAttribute.BACKGROUND); //null
      // do actual painting
   }
```

In fact most of the attributes relating to colour that I can find looking through the TextAttribute and GVT custom text attributes are coming back null. The `aci` object does have a list of non-null attributes but I can't figure out what the keys are from the debugger as they're all keyed off attribute lists.

The existing `paint` property of the `Graphics2D` object is usually set to the colour of the block that it has just drawn, meaning if I don't change things, I just get all my text appearing the same colour as the background, making it hard to read.

How can I find the colour for these text nodes that they are provided with in the original SVG?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It transpired that the `TextNode` is broken up into `TextRun`s and within the `TextRun` you can access the `PAINT_INFO` property of the `AttributedCharacterIterator` like this:

```
AttributedCharacterIterator runaci = textRun.getACI();
char c = runaci.first();
TextPaintInfo tpi = (TextPaintInfo) runaci.getAttribute(PAINT_INFO);
if ( tpi == null || !tpi.visible )
   {
      return y;
    }
g2d.setPaint(tpi.fillPaint);
```

The `TextPaintInfo` contains the data from the original SVG pertaining to the displayed text.